# is it possibile to open iTerm in current Finder position

Tags: macos, iterm2

Sometimes it could be very useful to open new iTerm window. I've seen this feature in Gnome window manager. It is possible to get same feature on MaxOsX? Is there a software to do that?

Comment: If you go to iTerm -> Profiles-> Open Profiles then you can create new profiles that will open in a specified directory. Finally, you can name them e.g. Desktop etc

Comment: see also this: http://peterdowns.com/posts/open-iterm-finder-service.html

Comment: updated solution: https://gist.github.com/ralfr/b505b664071980d1bd1f367455342e97

Comment: Read the iTerm FAQ, which explains how to do it and is mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67770202/128421).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Go to **System Settings** -> **Keyboard** -> **Keyboard Shortcuts** -> **Services** -> **Files and Folders** and give preferred shortcuts.

The shortcut will open iTerm at the selected folder, instead of from the folder that has been opened.

[image]

Comment: This is a very illuminating answer.

Comment: Thanks!, also you need to select a folder first and then press the shortcuts commands

Comment: for some reason this is not working for me in macOS Monterey (12.2.1): I've tried setting many different combinations and none work, with finder open and a folder selected.

Comment: On Monterey, configuring a shortcut doesn't override other shortcuts, and even using an unused shortcut doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: Setting to control+option+command+p worked for me, many other combinations do something else and then it doesn't work.

Comment: For the ones that can not make this to work using this answer (e.g. hearing a beep whenever you press the shortcut), you can follow this: https://superuser.com/a/1581374/1235371

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Sonoma. The only shortcut that works is `⌃ ⌥ ⌘ P`. However, it's buggy and only works properly when iTerm is already open. When the app is closed, this shortcut opens two iTerm windows: one at the current location and one at the directory you specified as *Working Directory* in you iTerm2 profile in *Preferences*. Unfortunately, the latter is in focus and you first need to close it. I tried using *App Shortcuts* as well, didn't work either. ‍♂️

Comment: you kinda need to select a file or folder in the location where you want to open iTerm - pretty lame implementation compared to windows and linux

Answer (score 40):

You can right-click on the folder where you want iTerm2 to open, then select `Services -> New iTerm2 Tab here`.

You can also find other options in the Services menu to open iTerm2 and Terminal.

This was tested on iTerm2 3.x and Catalina and above.

Comment: *This is the recommended solution in iTerm's FAQ.*

Answer (score 15):

**Problem with current solutions:** Doesn't work in *current* folder. Only if you right click a folder.

So do this:

1. In Finder, press <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to show the path bar.
2. Then, right click your folder and choose the option. Voila!

[image: Screenshot of Explanation]

If you don't see this entry, you first have to set iTerm2 as your default Terminal. In the menubar: `iTerm2 > Make iTerm2 Default Term`

Comment: Why don't I see this "New iTerm2 Window Here" menu when right clicking on that folder?

Comment: Maybe iTerm2 could not register the context menu entry. Try to reinstall iTerm2

Comment: No sorry, that didn't work. What worked was that I made iTerm2 my default terminal (menu >iTerm2 > Make iTerm2 Default Term). Now I can right click the folder as in your screenshot and open it in Terminal. That will open it in iTerm2.

Answer (score 10):

There are two apps called "Go2Shell" and "ShellHere". Both place a small icon at the top of the finder window. When the icon is clicked a terminal window opens in the same directory as the finder window.

#### Go2Shell

- Go2Shell can be downloaded from [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/go2shell/id445770608?mt=12) or [developer's website](https://zipzapmac.com/Go2Shell). It is possible that you won't be able to install it from Mac App Store, because Go2Shell wasn't updated for a long time.
- Go2Shell allows users to specify whether to open shell in **Terminal** or **iTerm2**.

#### ShellHere

- Shellhere can be downloaded from [here.](https://github.com/lhagan/ShellHere)
- ShellHere allows users to open a folder only in uses only MacOS Terminal.

Comment: Thanks, Go2Shell is awesome. For those of us that despise the app store, it's an easy download here: https://zipzapmac.com/Go2Shell

Comment: Chiming in in 2023 to note that Go2Shell works really well on macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 3):

Try https://github.com/wonderyue/Go2ShellAppleScript.
Something like Go2Shell. The latest update of Go2Shell is five years ago, due to the compatibility problem, I make a similar one with AppleScript.

Comment: Maybe you can share your AppleScript? Is it on github?

Comment: @ sensorario Yes, "this" is the link. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Cant see the link sorry

Comment: @ sensorario "this" in the original answer was the link. Never mind, I've modified the answer to make it more conspicuous.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open iTerm in current Finder position try the following:

**OpenInTerminal**

https://github.com/Ji4n1ng/OpenInTerminal

Alternative and a bit older

**TermHere**

https://hashbang.productions/apps/termhere/ (last updated on 2016)

Both work without issues in MacOS Catalina

cdto doesn't support opening the folder in iTerm, so its a no go

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have BetterTouchTool, you can just create a Finder trigger with action "Open Active/Selected Folder With Specific App" and select "iTerm". Works for me!

[BetterTouchTool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlP4f.png)

EDIT:
You can even add Hotkey Window hotkey before "Open Active/Selected Folder With Specific App" to open the terminal in the hotkey window (as a tab). Really neat.

[In hotkey window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw9VE.png)

Answer (score -1):

I've been using `cdto` forever before accidentally stumbling on to the accepted answer. Will definitely try out the accepted answer, but leaving a link to `cdto` here if someone finds in useful
https://github.com/jbtule/cdto

Comment: Just see that is no more maintained. =(

Comment: I don't think it works with iTerm